# vb.net get row index id by row or cell value

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview, indexof

hi i am trying to get index of row through its value . i tried this code but its not working is there any way where i can get indexof row by its value.

```
   Dim dgr As New DataGridViewRow()
        dgr.CreateCells(DataGridView1, New Object() {"name", "DFD", "SDFDF"})
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgr)
        txtNameIndex.Text = DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(dgr)
```

i want to add value and remove value by check box when the check box is checked then the value should be added in datagridviewd and when same check box is unchecked the value should be removed from datagridview

```
    If chkbox.Checked = True Then

        row = New String() {"2", "Product 2", "2000"}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    Else

        Value = New String() {"2", "Product 2", "2000"}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(Value)

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get an index:

```
Dim i as Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgr)
```

Or

```
Dim i as Integer = dgr.Index
```

For your checkbox code I recommend the top one since you aren't creating an object for the DataGridViewRow.